# Keeping only small window of output data in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark

I am interested in using Spark Structured Streaming for real-time data processing using data from for example last ~24hours of running, however I am not able to find correct solution for this problem.

Some useful information about entire situation:

- Data is constantly flowing all the time as an input for Spark so stream is active 24/7
- Spark does some actions and then writes some data to files(eg. parquet)
- Watermarking is used to reduce state size
- Someone wants to work on only most recent data returned from Spark Structured Streaming(for example all data from last 24 hours) to have a quick view on what happened in last time and for further very specific analysis.

From what I understand, watermarking helps managing state size so Spark does not hold entire data about the state. This is a good thing and solves one problem with 24/7 running.

The other problem is output data. Currently Spark appends the data and nothing else, this makes it grow bigger and bigger. Using memory sink for testing it creates memory problems. <s>I didn't try it with file sink because it creates one file for each record(ugh) so there's a risk of using all available inodes in system extremely quickly.</s> I can create one file per window with file sink.

So my question is:
Is it possible to force Spark Structured Streaming to delete output data after some amount of time when it is no longer needed? I want to keep output data only from for example last 24 hours. Is there any build-in solution or do I need to do it on my own? If I needed to do it on my own, wouldn't checkpoint data and spark metadata get corrupted?

Answer (score 0):

Using watermarking will allow us to keep only the last 24 hours

```
df.withWatermark("timestamp", "24 hours") //when timestamp is your event time field
```

From [Spark Spark doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#handling-late-data-and-watermarking)

> in Spark 2.1, we have introduced watermarking, which lets the engine
>   automatically track the current event time in the data and attempt to
>   clean up old state accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, I'm using watermarking but this cleans old state. State is needed to update old windows from what I understand so limiting it prevents from problems with this type of data but ignores late data. So Spark can't modify output data if state doesn't exist anymore. I understand it, however my problem is slightly different. Watermarking limits state data. I want to limit output data. State is one thing, output data is the other. So I want to know if there's a nice way to configure SSS to clean old output data. I can try it with scripts but it's quite dirty way.

Comment: @Tomasz what's your output data system?

Comment: Currently I'm testing file sink with parquet format. I'm reading quite big amount of data from Kafka and I'm doing 1sec windows. It means that spark creates one file per second. I'm using these files for Zeppelin visualization for example or for other analysis if there's something interesting in Zeppelin. However after some time I don't need these files anymore. I'm using Linux machine.

Comment: I would `partitionBy` date to only read the last X hours, and use a TTL on the folders/files